# Dynamic menu with ASP.NET repeater

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, webusercontrol

Currently i'm familiarizing myself with ASP.NET and i've stuck on a problem with dynamic content inside "ItemTemplate" of "Repeater". Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="sidebarRepeater" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <li>
               <a href="#<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></a>
           </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm getting a list of links with href == Id of current item and text of this item.
The problem is, that i need a "Onclick" asp.net handler for each of those links (this is menu of "Master" User control, and on each click i shall change contents of child user control, according to selected item in master).

Any tips?

Edit: I've already tryed to use LinkButton like:

```
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' runat="server" OnClick="ChangeSomething">
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

Edit2: Currently my markup looks like this:

```
<li>
    <input type="hidden" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>"
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton_Office" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'/>
</li>
```

In this case, it draws only a "hidden input" element only for first item in repeater.

Edit3: full listing of what i currently have(only `<li></li>` rendered into actual HTML):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="side-bar">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                <asp:Repeater ID="sidebarRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkSidebar" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' OnClick="linkMenu_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="contentPlaceholder" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also i forgot to say, that this is actually a .Net user control for Umbraco project.
Datasource is attached for repeater in `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method.

Comment: Why don't you use a `LinkButton` instead?

Comment: I've tryed to do so, but i don't know how to properly insert ID and Name of my listed code into it. When i've did insert through DataBinder.Eval like for this 'a' tag for LinkButton, it just didn't rendered.

Comment: You don't need to put all informations into your `LinkButton`, you just have to know which item was clicked, the rest can be obtained from other controls which might be hidden(f.e. for the `ID` you could use a `HiddenField`). You get the other controls via `FindControl` on the `NamimgContainer` of the `LinkButton` in it's `Click` event.

Comment: How to set the text for it according to current item in repeater?

Comment: You set the Text via `DataBinder.Eval`(as above) or via codebehind(`ItemDataBound` event).

Comment: Just tried to do as Motomoto Pink suggested, but element still is not rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, by adding `<form runat="server">` around my `<nav>` tag.
Seems like every of `<asp:button\linkbutton>` needs that in order to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="sidebarRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkMenu" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' OnClick="linkMenu_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This will keep "Id" field in **CommandArgument** and "Name" field in **Text** properties

In linkMenu_Click event handeler, you will get the Id and Name values as the sample code

```
protected void linkMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
    string id = link.CommandArgument;
    string name = link.Text;

    //Implement the different display of each menu here ...
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason. Code is identical to one, you've provided. But only <li> wrapper for this LinkButton is rendered, and only for first element in repeater.

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me. Could you please show me your recent code?

Comment: And you have linkMenu_Click event handler(with code as same as me) in code behide of MasterPage?

Comment: Yes, completely the same

Comment: Motto, thanks, but i've already solved this. It seems, that this "LinkButton" as well as "Button" need "form" tag with runat=server as a wrapper in order to work properly.

Comment: Ok, so you never wrap all code by the tag '<form runat="server">' since started. Great that you could solve it :)

Comment: I'm 100% new at classic ASP.NET, and don't have currently any normal literature to fill the basics. So yeah, i didn't knew about that one :) And thanks for all the help